# UILocalNotification with various alert body

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

How Can I repeat UILocalNotification with various alert body?

For example:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
notif.alertBody = @"Hello";
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

By using this code the notification will be repeated daily, how can I repeat the notification daily with different alert body each day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` method in the AppDelegate, and increase a 'day counter' variable. Then, schedule a new `UILocalNotification` with an array of strings for your notification's alert body. Use the day counter to get an updated string. Here's some example code:

In your AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int dayCount;
```

In your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self scheduleLocalNotification];
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    self.dayCount++;
    [self scheduleLocalNotification];
}

-(void)scheduleLocalNotification{
    NSArray *notifTextArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"Welcome", @"Hi there", nil];

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if(self.dayCount < notifTextArray.count){
        notif.alertBody = [notifTextArray objectAtIndex:self.dayCount];
    }
    else{
        self.dayCount = 0;
        notif.alertBody = [notifTextArray objectAtIndex:self.dayCount];
    }

    notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400]; //86400 seconds in a day
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

Just an option, but hope it helps.

Comment: @hw731: 2 questions - Are are not initialising new instance of UILocalNotification every time? what would happen is the user cancelled the notification when it appeared(pressed cancel button)?

Comment: I'll improve my answer.

Comment: @hw731: Repeating the previous question, this would not work if the user just cancelled the notification upon receiving it, would it? I mean, if the app was closed/in-background at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have scheduled a local notification, you cannot change any properties of the notification and the alert body as-well.

You may have to cancel the older notification and reschedule a new one to achieve this.