# using UILocalNotification with randomising strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have implemented UILocalNotification success on my project which i failed on randomising strings came from NSDictionary that i need to send whole worlds in each every 5 minute period. In every 5 minute, i need to pass random string in UILocalNotification.

Here is my example code :

```
    NSArray *word1Array= [_tmp objectForKey:@"word1"];

NSArray *word2Array = [_tmp objectForKey:@"word2"];

if([word1Array count] > 0)
{
    int minCount =  0;

    int totalcount = (int)[word1Array count];

    int randomIndex = (arc4random()%(totalcount-minCount))+minCount;

    NSString *word1 = [word1Array objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    NSString *word2 = [word2Array objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    NSString *wordbody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",word1,word2];

    UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    reminderNote.alertBody = wordbody;

    reminderNote.alertAction = @"Bak";

    reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";

    reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 5];

    reminderNote.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];


}
```

This codes starts to send notification with randomised strings but every 5 minutes, it passed 4-5 words same time which is really annoying. How can i fixed it for just sends 1 string in each 5 minute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you get the same string for N times at minute 5th. It is because you schedule the Local Notification at the same time.

You should put the above code into something like:-

```
for(int i=1;i<=5 ;i++){
   //Your other code

   reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 5 * i];

   //Your other code
}
```

The above code will schedule to local notification for 5 times, it will notify the user at minute 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 from the current time.

**Update Answer**:-

> Each application on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local
>   notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess
>   of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the
>   soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

See: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

Schedule a new Local Notification after another: [UILocalNotification with various alert body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792997/uilocalnotification-with-various-alert-body)

Comment: How about if I would like make it infinite loop. I mean it will send Local Notification over 5 minutes period. It will send forever in every 5 minutes instead of  5 word * 5 = 25 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are limits for everything. You can at most have 64 scheduled local notifications. Unless you find out a way to schedule smartly one after another. See the updated answer above.

Comment: Note: **Recurring notification** will have the same alert message. This might help on schedule one after another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792997/uilocalnotification-with-various-alert-body

Comment: Thank you for these informations, Better way to keep loop in 64 times , after user tap any time in 64 times loop period, in applicationDidbecomeActive , I can reset LocalNotifications with new randomized words right ? If user does not occur any action in 64 times that means user does not like that app :)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just make sure that it will not annoy the user too much as well.